# maven plugin for docker (e.g. to run with needed db)

Tags: maven, docker, maven-plugin

Making an image for maven project should be straightforward, as maven know how to build (and can know how to run)

How to build docker image and run it with maven?

Let's say the app also needs MongoDB, that I can run as `docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo`. Is it possible also to specify with some maven plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The maven plugin created by fabric8 allows you to do this:

the plugin and its documentation is available on github: https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin

The samples include for example https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/samples/data-jolokia-demo/pom.xml (which seems to be similar to what you plan).

An alternative could be using Docker-compose and some scripts outside maven, once the images are created.